Does a non-commutative ring with unity necessarily have a maximal two-sided ideal?
Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring with unity. By Zorn's lemma, $R$ must have a maximal left ideal and a maximal right ideal.
Then, does the ring $R$ necessarily have a maximal two-sided ideal?

Unless I'm missing something Zorn's lemma also shows that $R$ has a maximal two-sided ideal. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the poset consisting of all two-sided ideals of $R$ which don't contain $1$. $\mathbb{P}$ satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma since both "is a two-sided ideal" and "doesn't contain $1$" are finitary conditions. So by Zorn's lemma, $\mathbb{P}$ has a maximal element $M$. (Unitality of $R$ is used here to reduce "proper two-sided ideal" to a finitary condition; in the context of non-unital rings, the union of a chain of proper two-sided ideals need not be proper.)

Yes, you are right. The proof is very similar to the case of the existence of maximal left and right ideals. Thank you so much for your hint.
